# Two matrices with Gershgorin circles similars

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If a matrix $A$ and $B$ have the same elements on the diagonal, that is, the same centers of the Gershgorin circles, and the radii of each disk of $A$ are almost equal to the radii of the disks of $B$, I can say that the values eigenvalues ​​of $A$ are almost equal to the eigenvalues ​​of $B$?

Comment: Eigenvalues can „move“ within the connected components of the union of the Gershgorin circles. So if all Gershgorin circles are pairwise disjoint (both for $A$ and $B$) you can find some bound given by the maximal radii, but this gets messier if the circles are not pairwise disjoint. Moreover since the bound does depend on the radii of the Gershgorin circles and not really on the fact that these radii are almost equal, I am not sure if one could say that the eigenvalues are almost equal, since Gershgorin circles can potentially be large.

Comment: The matrix  $ B $ is ​​made up of $ A $ plus a small disturbance in some components.